# Excel: Summing rounded values which could contain values that are not a number

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to take the sum of the rounded values of a range, I got this working using

`=SUM(ROUND(A2:A5,0))`

Which would result in the sum of

```
4.7
9.2
11.4
15.4
```

to be `5+9+11+15` or `40`

But now if one of those is not a number I want to count those as `0`

```
4.7
9.2
ABC
15.4
```

Should result in `5+9+0+15` or `29`

Tried applying `SUMIF` somehow but I can't get it to work. Anyone got any suggestions on how to achieve this in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(ROUND(A2:A5,0),0))
```

This is an array formula so you must press ctrl+shift+enter when entering it.